# How to bind and automatically refresh ItemsSource when I'm binding to some Entity from DbSet?

Tags: wpf, binding, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to make use of EntityFramework and WPF data binding for the first time.

I have some ListBox. I have set `ItemsSource` to `SomeDbContext.SomeEntity.ToList();` programatically and I have set my binding like this:

```
<ListBox Name="listbox" Margin="4" SelectedValuePath="Address" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                 <Label Content="{Binding Id}"></Label>
                 <Label Content="{Binding Address}"></Label>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
<Button Click="ButtonTest_Click">Open</Button>
```

I'm adding new item to my DbSet and I expected that my list will refresh after `SomeDbContext.SaveChanges();` method call, but it didn't.

My Window code behind:

```
    DatabaseContext _dbContext = new DatabaseContext();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lb.ItemsSource = _dbContext.Addresses.ToList();
        // I have tried to set source to _dbContext
    }

    private void ButtonTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _dbContext.Addresses.Add(new Adresses() { Address = "192.168.1.2:502" });
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Here is my Entity:

```
public class Adresses
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

My DbContext:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Adresses> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

I guess that my approach is wrong, because I'm creating new object when I'm setting `ItemsSource` to `_dbContext.Addresses.ToList();`, but I have no idea how to bind directly to my DbSet (or is it possible).

Comment: I would manage Addresses as a viewmodel property `ObservableCollection<Addresses> Addresses`. Bind that (in XAML, not codebehind) to the listbox's ItemsSource, and changes to Addresses will be reflected in UI. When user wants to save to DB, update `_dbContext.Addresses` from the observablecollection, and then save.

Comment: What you're doing wrong is that `ToList()` makes a copy, and incidentally it's a copy that doesn't raise any events when it changes, so even if you did update it, the listbox has no way of knowing it should update.

Comment: Easiest thing would be `lb.ItemsSource = _dbContext.Addresses.ToList();` all over again at the end of `ButtonTest_Click`, but that's not a real solution to the real problem. BTW `Address` ought to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`